# It is possible to see clients who connected to my hostednetwork?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I set up a hosted network with my laptop using Windows 7.

I want to check all the clients who connected to it. Is it possible?

And is there any tool can manage it? For example, limit the net speed or something similar.

Comment: Do you want to see list of clients like hostname - IP-address or this should be list which will also include type of device - smartphone,tablet PC, PC, laptop?

Comment: I want to see information as much as possible. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To view connected clients use command line

```
@echo off
netsh wlan show hostednetwork | findstr -i status
echo SSID Name
netsh wlan show hostednetwork | findstr -i " ssid "
netsh wlan show hostednetwork setting=security
echo Connected clients
arp -a | findstr -i 192.168.173 | findstr /V 255 | findstr /V 192.168.173.1
```

For bandwith control you can use NetLimiter.
http://www.netlimiter.com/products/netlimiter-4

Comment: Nice answer! Windows10 now uses `192.168.137.*` as **default** subnet for hostednetwork. You can always change this on the device's tcp/ip v4/6 properties.

Answer (score 2):

Important thing to remember is that typically there is no DHCP server running on computer hosts. What this means is that there will be no IP address automatically assigned as is typically done when using a wireless router or access point.

Two options are available: either to use `APIPA` addressing (169.254.0.0/16) which will permit a connection between the two computers automatically when a DHCP server is unable to be contacted or using static IP addressing.

The two computers’ addresses can be seen in each other’s ARP tables using `arp -a` command in Command Prompt.

You cannot limit internet connection speed on W7 host with built-in features.

Comment: I didn't find DHCP server service from my service list through services.msc. But all the devices that connect to my hostednetwork got a IP like 192.168.137.XXX. I didn't set any static IP address on devices. So I am confused.

Comment: It looks like you created ad-hoc network and enabled ICS, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just type arp -a at a command prompt.

In the list that is shown, find the adapter with the IP 192.168.137.1 and under this the first addresses are the ones assigned to clients sharing the connection.

My first client address was 192.168.137.251 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's super simple, actually.

`ping 192.168.1.255` (insert your subnet's broadcast address in place of mine if different)

`arp -a` to see all the clients that are on and actively responding to broadcast pings

The only reason I had included the ping command is for those that clear their arp table on a regular basis.